# ISOWeek error in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

My problem is with SQL Server 2008. If I execute:

```
Select dbo.IsoWeek(Getdate())
```

I get this error

> Msg 4121, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Cannot find either column "dbo" or the user-defined function or aggregate "dbo.IsoWeek", or the name is ambiguous.

Running the same command on another database gives me the expected response: "30"

Is there a cause for this?

Comment: IsoWeek is not an integrated sql-function afaik. Maybe you have a userdefined function in your other database?

Comment: You are right. Meanwhile, analyzing the problem I found the function in the other database. Tnx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no built in SQL Server function called `ISOWeek`, does the database you're running the query in (where it works) have a [user defined function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/user-defined-functions/user-defined-functions) called `ISOWeek` present?

A syntax that will work from a built-in, using the [`DATEPART`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datepart-transact-sql) function is:

```
SELECT DATEPART(ISO_WEEK, GETDATE())
```

Which will return `30` at the time of writing, i.e. if you call it with:

```
SELECT DATEPART(ISO_week, '2017-07-28 00:00:00.000')
```

Comment: Thank you, Rob. I have found the function Isoweek in the database where it works. From now on, I wil use the built-in function to avoid future situations like this.

Comment: byte00, glad I could help =) My guess is that the function in the database where it does work *probably* just calls `DATEPART` anyway! =) 

If you found my answer solved your problem, it' convention on stackoverflow (I see you only created your account today, welcome!) to click on the "tick" to the left of the answer text to mark it as "accepted". You can also up-vote answers that helped by clicking the upward pointing arrow over the "0" that's also to the right of the answer. Both of these "reward" people with reputation which encourages them to provide answers =)

Comment: Yes, it does. I may post the function here if it helps. May I? I am new to this forum and I do not know what rules apllies here.